# Swagger @ApiModelProperty example value null for Long

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, springfox

I use [SpringFox](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/) and Swagger UI for API documentation.
I have a DTO in which there is a property which is of type Long. It's not populated 99% of time so I want to demonstrate this fact in documentation by setting the property value to `null`. So I want this JSON in examples section

```js
{
  /* ... */
  "legacyId": null
}
```

I've already tried

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "legacyId", example = null)
public Long getLegacyId() {
    return legacyId;
}
```

But I got a warning "Attribute value must be constant". What else I can do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#overriding-property-datatypes), there is no null dataType. You have two options

1. You can define as

   ```
   @ApiModelProperty(example = "null") --> This will display as "null"
   ```

   This will mislead the user and might lead to NPE
2. `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)`

personally, I would prefer second one because, when spring maps the json from UI in your controller, if nothing is passed from frontend, it will be null automatically.