# Swagger UI - nullable values

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

We have a SpringBoot (version 1.5.12) REST Api with springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui (version 2.9.2)

Is it possible to have nullable properties in Swagger UI (using swagger.yaml configuration file or swagger annotations)?

The payload that we need to send is something like this:

```
{ 
  id: 2
  name: 'test'
  surname: null
}
```

`Surname` should be a string or null (by default null).
If not possible, can we override some swagger classes to obtain this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: @ApiModelProperty(required = false, value = ".....")
public String surname

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to have nullable/optional properties. To do so set the `required` attribute in `@ApiModelProperty` (`io.swagger.annotations`) annotation to false (it is actually false by default).

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = false, value = "Surname")
private String surname;
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to work. We need that in swagger UI, when we click on "Try It Out", the value of surname is null (we tried also `@ApiModelProperty(example = null)`  but there is a compilation error)

Comment: Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032676/swagger-apimodelproperty-example-value-null-for-long It seems like it is not possible what you is trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, maybe is it possible to have a custom DataType in Swagger UI?